# How to highlight all cells that contain formulas

Tags: libreoffice, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc

In LibreOffice Calc, I want to be able to quickly distinguish between cells that contain input data and formulas. Enabling "View → Value Highlighting" changes the font color in cells such that cells containing formulas have green text, and cells containing numbers have blue text. For example:

[image: LibreOffice Calc Value Highlighting]

However, these colors are not obvious enough for me. I would like LibreOffice to change the background color of the cells containing formulas instead of just changing the font color. Is there a way to change the background color of all cells that contain formulas so that they stand out from all the other cells?

For example, something like this which can be easily toggled on and off for cells that contain formulas:

[image: LibreOffice formula cell with background color]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not difficult to implement.

First, let's figure out how a cell with data differs from a cell with a formula. For your example, the distinguishing feature would be the **=** sign in the leftmost position. In other words, the condition

`=LEFT(FORMULA(A1);1)="="`

will return **TRUE** if cell **A1** contains a formula.

It should be noted that for array formulas of the `{=A1:A3}` type, the sign of the formula will be a curly bracket followed by an equal sign **{=**. Therefore, the condition will be slightly different -

`=LEFT(FORMULA(A1);2)="{="`

By combining these two conditions with the OR() function, you can check any cell on the sheet.

Now let's think about the easiest way to implement your requirement *"easily toggle on and off"*

Select a cell on the sheet that will certainly not interfere with your calculations, for example, **AA1**. You can set it to "Do not print" in its format.

[image: Hide When Print]

Now, in a convenient place on the sheet, insert a checkbox and link it to cell **AA1** through the ***Linked cell*** property

[image: Set Checkbox]

There is very little left - select the entire sheet (or only that part of it where you want to see formulas / values) and create a conditional format for this range.

[image: Conditional Formattinf]

The condition described by the formula

`AND($AA$1;OR(LEFT(FORMULA(A1);1)="=";LEFT(FORMULA(A1);2)="{="))`

means the following - *"if the checkbox is checked **AND** the formula in the cell begins with **=** **OR** with **{=**"*

Set the style with the bright background you see fit.

Click on the checkbox and make sure everything works as it should.

[image: Test]

Comment: Not sure I agree with "This is not difficult to implement" — that would be better left up to the reader to decide. Also, as I've mentioned in the past, animated GIFs are painful for me to read — I'd prefer answers that don't have [moving stuff in them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/blink). But those are cosmetic issues — +1 for a good answer.